# Snakemake in cluster mode with --no-shared-fs: How to set cluster-status

Tags: snakemake

I'm running Snakemake in a cluster environment and would like to use S3 as shared file system for writing output files.

Options `--default-remote-provider`, `--default-remote-prefix` and `--no-shared-fs` are set accordingly. The cluster uses UGE as scheduler, so setting `--cluster` is straightforward, but how do I set `--cluster-status`, whose use is enforced when using `--no-shared-fs`?

My best guess was a naive `--cluster-status "qstat -j"` which resulted in

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'qstat Your job 2 ("snakejob.bwa_map.1.sh") has been submitted' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

So I guess my question is, how do I get the actual jobid in there?

Thanks!

Andreas

EDIT 1:
I found https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/7cyqAIfgeq4, so cluster-status has to be a script. So I wrote a Python script that is able to parse the above line, however snakemake still fails with:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/home/ec2-user/clusterstatus.py Your job 2 ("snakejob.bwa_map.1.sh") has been submitted'
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/ec2-user/clusterstatus.py 
Your job 2 ("snakejob.bwa_map.1.sh") has been submitted' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

First, I needed the -terse option for qsub (which I had not added at first in my case and snakemake somehow remembered the wrong cluster command

Secondly, the cluster-status argument needs to point to a script being able to get the job status (job id being the only argument) and output "failed", "running" or "success".